# How to get sum of onload inputs

Tags: javascript, input, load, addition, preload

HTML:

```
<table id="tab1">
    <tr id="maint">
      <td style="background-color:white;"></td>
      <td>słowo klucz</td>
      <td>ilość wynikow google</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="maint">słowo klucz</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="klucz" value="" required></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="wyszkiwania" value=""  onblur="sumX()" onkeyup="operatorf()" id="eq"required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="maint">słowo klucz</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="klucz" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="wyszkiwania" value="" onblur="sumX()"  onkeyup="operatorf()" id="eq"required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
var wejscie = document.getElementById('eq').value;

  if ( wejscie <= 100000) {
    var stawka13 = 59;
    var stawka46 = stawka13*0.75;
    var stawka710 = stawka46*0.55;
  }
  else {
    var stawka13 = wejscie/100000*59;
    if (stawka13 > 210) {
      stawka13 = 210;
    }
    var stawka46 = stawka13*0.75;
    var stawka710 = stawka46*0.55;
  }

  stawka13 = Math.round(stawka13).toFixed(2);
  stawka46 = Math.round(stawka46).toFixed(2);
  stawka710 = Math.round(stawka710).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('sum13').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sum46').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sum710').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sum13').innerHTML = " "+sum13+" zł";
  document.getElementById('sum46').innerHTML = " "+sum46+" zł";
  document.getElementById('sum710').innerHTML = " "+sum710+" zł";
```

I would like to get an sum of it but with this eq. 
I try arr etc but aint work "properly" as I want. 
My target is just sum all of it with all math in it.
I'm not allowed to add jq to it so it is impotant to stay on meta.

Comment: IDs should be unique to the document. The HTML you are showing has multiple IDs of the same value. The HTML also doesn't match your JavaScript code. Please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Don't worry I got outputs problem is that I cant get all verified one by one and I need to do it easy as possible so all of problem included in script for sure.